# Scala Stream call-by-need (lazy) vs call-by-name

Tags: scala, stream

So I understand that call-by-need is simply a memoized version of call-by-name. In Martin Odersky's FP Course on Coursera, in lecture 7.3 (Lazy Evaluation), he mentions that if Streams were implemented using call-by-name, then it could potentially lead to a blowup in computational complexity.

What would be an example of such a blowup?

Call-by-name:

```
def cons[T](hd: T, tl: => Stream[T]) = new Stream[T] {
  def head = hd
  def tail = tl
  ...
}
```

Call-by-need:

```
def cons[T](hd: T, tl: => Stream[T]) = new Stream[T] {
  def head = hd
  lazy val tail = tl
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For example the Fibonacci series, implemented by adding the previous two elements to form the successor. Without memoization, that would have a linear slowdown (and stack growth) in the length of the sequence:

```
scala> lazy val fib: Stream[Int] = Stream.cons(0,
     | Stream.cons(1, fib.zip(fib.tail).map(p => p._1 + p._2)))
fib: Stream[Int] = Stream(0, ?)
```

Example lazily (-sic-) copied from [this blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20160621035805/http://www.scala-blogs.org:80/2007/12/project-euler-fun-in-scala.html)

Comment: Please check link,

Answer (score 0):

`def` and `lazy val` are both lazy. The difference is that `def` is re-evaluated every time it is called. `lazy val` is only evaluated the first time it is called and any call to it just looks to the first evaluated value.

Using `def` would mean re-evaluated `tail` every time it is called.

```scala
def randDef: () => Int = {
  val r = scala.util.Random.nextInt
  () => r
}

val randVal: () => Int = {
  val r = scala.util.Random.nextInt
  () => r
}

lazy val randLazyVal: () => Int = {
  val r = scala.util.Random.nextInt
  () => r
}
// defined function randDef
// randVal: () => Int = ammonite.$sess.cmd18$Helper$$Lambda$2545/0x00000008013a4430@7466fa3
// randLazyVal: () => Int = [lazy]

randDef()
// res8: Int = -693604502
randDef()
// res9: Int = 2056941756
randDef eq randDef
// res15: Boolean = false

randVal()
// res11: Int = 3
randVal()
// res12: Int = 3
randVal eq randVal
// res16: Boolean = true

randLazyVal()
// res13: Int = 99
randLazyVal()
// res14: Int = 99
randLazyVal eq randLazyVal
// res17: Boolean = true
```